# Primefaces - Ajax commandButton

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have a problem , ajax the way it is in the low code does not call the `exampleController.include( )`
Someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

```
         <h:form id="exampleForm">

            <p:panel toggleable="true" id="pgInfo">

               <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="2">
                  <p:inputMask value="" id="val"/>
               </h:panelGrid>

               <h:panelGrid columns="3" cellpadding="3">
                  <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-disk" 
                    value="Add"
                    actionListener="#{exampleController.include()}" 
                    ajax="true" update="dataTable" process="pgInfo"/>  
               </h:panelGrid>

            </p:panel>

            <p:panel toggleable="true" id="panelTable" >
               <h:panelGrid columns="1" cellpadding="1">
                  <p:dataTable id="dataTable">

                     ...

                  </p:dataTable>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </p:panel>

     </h:form>
```

Comment: Most likely one of the reasons mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/commandlink-commandbutton-ajax-backing-bean-action-listener-method-not-invoked

Comment: I still can not identify the error here. tks

Comment: Post your bean code (minimalistic but fully functional and valid) and did you check your method signature? Client side console logging, client side network tab etc?

Comment: The method of the controller is not called and therefore does not generate error on the console.

Comment: The **CLIENT** side consol can log alllll kinds of things even if a method on the server is not called. Please read and answer questions carefully.

Comment: Sorry friend , I see here and post. tks